# replace ClassName with custom string to display in IntelliJ scalatest window

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

For a specific use case, we are trying to replace

**ClassName** with **Verifying ClassName**

in IntelliJ scala test case window.

For that, we overridden toString method in spec class as below :-

```
override def toString: String = s"Verifying ${getClass.getSimpleName}"
```

Still in IntelliJ test class, we can see only test ClassName name.

Kindly suggest, how to implement it.

[image]

Comment: `toString` won't change the class name.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this

Comment: I don't think so.